# Clean text files - remove unwanted content in LOOP (R/python)

Tags: python, r, loops, data-cleaning

[image]I want to clean all the "waste" (making the files unsuitable for analysis) in unstructured text-files.

In this specific situation, one option to only retain the wanted information, is to only retain all numbers above 250 (the text is a combination of string, numbers, ...)

For a large number of text files, I want to do follow action in R:

```
x <- x[which(x >= "250"),]
```

The code for 1 text file works perfectly (above), when I try to do the same in a loop (for the large N of text files, it fails (error: incorrect number of dimensions o)).

```
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  i<- i[which(i >= "250"),]
}
```

Anyone any idea how to solve this in R (or python) ?

picture: very simplified example of a text file, I want to retain everything between (START) and (END)

Comment: can you give a sample of data ? It's pretty easy to do.

Comment: e.g. the files are starting with  1/4/1993 - 9UTC- Index: ZR- T-S- RH-G% , followed by 10^4 number of numeric records in scientific notation (e.g. 2.774E+02) , halfway the file, there is again unwanted info/text (the second half of each text file should be deleted entirely).   --> As mentioned, I can manage it perfect to do it for 1 file separately, but the code does no longer work in a loop that loops trough all files

Comment: I added a very simplified example of a text file at the top of the original post

Comment: oh, so you are reading different files from a path, you want to delete the file which doesn't have 250 ?

Comment: What is the output of this line? `x <- x[which(x >= "250"),] `

Comment: No, I have many files (10 thousands) and I want to do the same for each file in only a small code lines

Comment: The statement that works for 1 file, returns the file in which only numbers larger than 250 are retained, all the rest is deleted as I want , but I will do this for 10000 files.

Comment: `files` variable is containing the list of files in the folder?

Comment: yes, indeed. ...

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense if it is 10 K files, why are you even trying to do in R or python? Why not just a simple `awk` or bash command? Moreover, your images is parsing info between START and END from the text files, not sure if it is data frame with columns across ( try to put in a simple `dput`  rather than images.)
All you are trying to do is a `grep` between start and end across 10 k files. I would do that in bash. 
something like this in bash should work.

```
for i in *.txt
do 
 sed -n '/START/,/END/{//!p}' i > i.edited.txt
done
```

If the columns are standard across in R you can do the following ( But, I would not read 10 K files in R memory). 
read the files as a list of dataframe Then simply do an lapply

```
a = data.frame(col1 = c(100,250,300))
b = data.frame(col1 = c(250,450,100,346))
c = data.frame(col1 = c(250,123,122,340))

df_list <- list(a = a ,b = b,c = c)
lapply(df_list, subset, col1 >= 250)
```